# When I run this it is showing ffmpeg has no attribute input. How to solve this?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

```
def extract_audio_from_video(file_path: str) -> np.ndarray:
    inputfile = ffmpeg.input(file_path)
    out = inputfile.output('-', format='f32le', acodec='pcm_f32le', ac=1, ar='44100')
    raw = out.run(capture_stdout=True)
    del inputfile, out
    return np.frombuffer(raw[0],np.float32)
```

Comment: There are several different ffmpeg wrapper modules for Python, and they don't all work the same.  Which one did you install, EXACTLY?

Comment: ffmpeg-python,ffmpeg,ffmpegio,FFmpeg 64-bit static Windows build from www.gyan.dev

Comment: Got the output....... used same code but intalled ffmpeg for windows and dragged ffmpeg and ffprobe  .exe files to the script where i'm running code then it came....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to explore a different option, check out [my `ffmpegio` package:

```
pip install ffmpegio
```

```py
import ffmpegio

fs,x = ffmpegio.audio.read(file_path, sample_fmt='f32le', ac=1, ar=44100)
# fs - actual sampling rate
# x - [nx1] numpy array
```

Comment: WARNING:root:Failed to auto-detect ffmpeg and ffprobe executable.

Comment: Where are your ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe located? See [this doc](https://python-ffmpegio.github.io/python-ffmpegio/install.html#install-ffmpeg-program) for where `ffmpegio` would look for the executables.

Answer (score 1):

Got the output....... used same code but intalled ffmpeg for windows and dragged ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe files to the script where i'm running code then it came....
I Went through the installation procedure and came to know that ffmpeg should be installed and then ffmpeg-python should be installed.
After that I gave path of ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe in systemvariables and dragged them to script where i'm running code..
Then it ran without any errors.